# Passing an image as a prop

Tags: reactjs, react-props

I am trying to pass an image as a prop from my Matchups object to my TeamGrid component.

Home.js

```
import React from "react";
import TeamGrid from "./TeamGrid.js";
import Prediction from "./Prediction.js";
import GridContainer from "./GridContainer.js";

//Matchups
import Matchups from "./Matchups.js";

export default function TeamSection() {
  return (
    <div>
      <GridContainer>
        <TeamGrid logo={Matchups[0].homeImg} alt={Matchups[0].homeAlt} />
        <Prediction />
        <TeamGrid logo={Matchups[0].awayImg} alt={Matchups[0].awayAlt} />
      </GridContainer>
    </div>
  );
}
```

TeamGrid.js

```
export default function TeamGrid(props) {
  const classes = useStyles();
  const imageClasses = classNames(
    classes.imgRaised,
    classes.imgRoundedCircle,
    classes.imgFluid
  );
  return (
    <GridItem xs={12} sm={12} md={4}>
      <Button color="primary">
        <Card plain>
          <GridItem xs={12} sm={12} md={6} className={classes.itemGrid}>
            <img
              src={require("../../assets/teams/${this.props.logo}")}
              alt={this.prop.alt}
              className={imageClasses}
            />
          </GridItem>
          <h4 className={classes.cardTitle}>
            Team
            <br />
            <small className={classes.smallTitle}>Record</small>
          </h4>
        </Card>
      </Button>
    </GridItem>
  );
}
```

Matchups.js

```
export const Matchups = [
  {
    homeImg: "Seahawks.gif",
    homeAlt: "Seahawks",
    awayImg: "Vikings.gif",
    awayAlt: "Vikings"
  },
  {
    homeImg: "Titans.gif",
    homeAlt: "Titans",
    awayImg: "Jaguars.gif",
    awayAlt: "Jaguars"
  }
];
```

I am currently getting: "TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined"

I am learning React as I go with this project so any help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

Could you try like this:

```
import React from "react";
import TeamGrid from "./TeamGrid.js";
import Prediction from "./Prediction.js";
import GridContainer from "./GridContainer.js";

//Matchups
import {Matchups} from "./Matchups.js";

export default function TeamSection() {
  return (
    <div>
      <GridContainer>
        <TeamGrid logo={Matchups[0].homeImg} alt={Matchups[0].homeAlt} />
        <Prediction />
        <TeamGrid logo={Matchups[0].awayImg} alt={Matchups[0].awayAlt} />
      </GridContainer>
    </div>
  );
}
```

I think that your problem is that your constant is not exported as default object for given file. So you have multiple solutions:

1. you can decompose object when you import it: `import {Matchups} from "./Matchups.js";`
2. you could used imported object and access constant as property of object

   ````
   ...
   <TeamGrid logo={matchup.Matchups[0].homeImg} alt={matchup.Matchups[0].homeAlt} />```
   ````